# launch flutter_local_notifications use firebase_messaging when app is terminated

Tags: android, flutter

I try to send notification to my user when my app is terminated. To use this i use firebase_messaging and flutter_local_notifications. It work perfectly when app is foreground or background, but when app is terminated is not work. This my code:

```
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  if(message.notification != null) {
    handleScreen(message);
  }

  NotificationService().showNotification(
          title: screen,
          body: "cool",
          payLoad: "payload there"
      );
}

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
  
  await NotificationService().initNotification()

  // Gestion firebase_messaging
  FirebaseMessaging messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
  
await messaging.requestPermission(
    alert: true,
    announcement: false,
    badge: true,
    carPlay: false,
    criticalAlert: false,
    provisional: false,
    sound: true,
  );

  FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      handleScreen(message);
  });

  FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage().then((message) {
    if(message != null) {
        handleScreen(message);
    }
  });

  FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
    if(message.notification != null) {
      handleScreen(message);
    }
  });

  runApp(const MyAppScreen());
}

class NotificationService {
  final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin notificationsPlugin =
  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  Future<void> initNotification() async {
    AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid =
    const AndroidInitializationSettings('app_icon');

    var initializationSettingsIOS = DarwinInitializationSettings(
        requestAlertPermission: true,
        requestBadgePermission: true,
        requestSoundPermission: true,
        onDidReceiveLocalNotification:
            (int id, String? title, String? body, String? payload) async {});

    var initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
        android: initializationSettingsAndroid,
        iOS: initializationSettingsIOS);

    await notificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
        onDidReceiveNotificationResponse:
            (NotificationResponse notificationResponse) async {});
  }

  notificationDetails() {
    return const NotificationDetails(
        android: AndroidNotificationDetails('channelId', 'channelName',
            importance: Importance.max),
        iOS: DarwinNotificationDetails());
  }

  Future showNotification(
      {int id = 0, String? title, String? body, String? payLoad}) async {
    return notificationsPlugin.show(
        id, title, body, await notificationDetails());
  }
}
```

When i send this notification with POSTMAN:

```
{
  "to": "/topics/weather",
   "notification": {
    "title": "test",
    "body": "test"
  },
  "data": {
    "screen": "aide",
    "id": "value2",
    "level": "",
    "subject": "",
    "click_action": "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK"
  }
}
```

I received FCM notification and flutter_local_notification if app is background, foreground or terminated.

But when i send notification with only data field:

```
{
  "data": {
    "screen": "aide",
    "id": "value2",
    "level": "",
    "subject": "",
    "click_action": "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK"
  }
}
```

FCM not display message it is normal, but flutter_local_notification display message in foreground, background but not if app is terminated.

Why ?

```
firebase_messaging: ^14.4.1
flutter_local_notifications: ^14.0.0+1
```

Everybody can help me ? Thank you